# Getting activity back from ForegroundService

Tags: android, xamarin, mobile

So I'm creating app that includes ForegoundService with is sending some data to the backend.

I've already made service part. In activity i have two buttons, like start and stop.

Pushing start is starting the service and pushing stop needs to stop him. The problem is that when I reopen the app (from icon, or from notification) the service reference is null and I can't stop service working.

Is it possible to reopen that exact activity event when app was already closed?

I was thinking about making service singleton, but i wish there is some proper way to do this.

Comment: You are looking for what is called an "Android Bound Service"  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/services/creating-a-service/bound-services#:~:text=Bound%20Services%20in%20Xamarin.Android%201%20Bound%20Services%20Overview.,About%20the%20Service%20Connection%20and%20the%20Binder.%20

Comment: Do you mean you want to find a way to shutdown the ForegroundService ?If yes,you could use `AddAction` when you create the notification,add a stop service event.

Comment: Not only, i want to find a way to "resume" previous activity. I`d like to "resume" app by clicking icon as well

Comment: When you click the notification,you could lanch the activity which you want by pendingintent.you could refer to the [sample](https://github.com/xamarin/monodroid-samples/tree/master/ApplicationFundamentals/ServiceSamples/ForegroundServiceDemo).